# Integral closure of k-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a finitely generated algebra over $k$ that doesn't have zero divisors. Why is the integral closure of $A$ a finitely generated module over $A$ ?

(edited)

Comment: This is not true in general. But it holds when $A$ is f.g. over $k$, by a famous theorem of Emmy Noether.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin said in the comments, the result is not true in general but holds if $A$ is finitely generated over $k.$ This follows from Proposition 16 (page 46) of Serre's Local Algebra:

> Proposition 16. Let $A$ be a domain which is a finitely generated algebra over a field $k,$ let $K$ be its field of fractions, and let $L$ be a finite extension of $K.$ Then the integral closure $B$ of $A$ in $L$ is a finitely generated $A$-module (in particular it is a finitely generated $k$-algebra).

The Google Books [preview](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/Local_Algebra.html?id=oZmXsvlYtMQC&redir_esc=y) of Serre's book lets one see page 46 (and surprisingly, most of the book).

Comment: This is also contained in any other complete text on commutative algebra, for example Eisenbud's book.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You are of course correct. I should have mentioned that this in many commutative algebra books and I linked to Serre's book simply because I wanted to provide an online reference and that was the first one I found.

Comment: Remark: the statement Proposition 16 is the same as saying "fields are universally Japanese", see [032R](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/032R), [032F](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/032F). For a SP based proof, note that fields are Nagata (see definition in first link), so it suffices to apply [0334](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0334).